# linear gradient from CSS versus linear gradient from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am a beginner. Trying to diagonally split up a table cell from Javascript. I know how to do it from CSS.

Below some test code. In cells 1, 2, 3, 4 and 6 I have the result I want using CSS. However, I will have to fill the background from Javascript since I have to calculate the location of the cell.

i found on this forum what they use (for Chrome), see also in my test code, however, I can get it to work like the result I get with CSS. Anyone knows how to do it? thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
        element {
            --main-px-size: 18px;
        }

        td {
            background: linear-gradient( to bottom right, rgb(255, 255, 255) 50%, rgb(0, 255, 0) 50%);
        }

        #id1 {
            background-color: rgb(200, 100, 200);
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: var(--main-px-size);
            font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
        }

        .class1 {
            background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            text-align: center;
            font-size: var(--main-px-size);
            font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body id="bod">
    <table id="id1" style="width:10%">
        <tr>
            <th>one</th>
            <th>two</th>
            <th>six</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="td1" class="class1">1</td>
            <td id="td2" class="class1">2</td>
            <td id="td3" class="class1">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="td4" class="class1">4</td>
            <td id="td5" class="class1">5</td>
            <td id="td6" class="class1">6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>

        function drawHalfCell(id, col1, col2) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.background = "-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom right," + col1 + " 50%, " + col2 + " 50%)";
        }

        drawHalfCell("td5", "red", "blue");

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just use the same rule that is in your css, get rid of that webkit one

Comment: thanks a lot. I didn't try that :) it works

Comment: @epascarello please move your comment to an answer

Comment: Don't apply `style` using JS; instead use `classList.add` and `classList.remove` along with a CSS class that does your gradient.

Comment: thanks, I'm lacking some background but I will look into it